# How to Parameterize More Than Two Textboxes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to parameterize the 5 textfields and one button-press using Jxl parameterization. I have done only two textboxes, I can't get how to parameterize those 5 textboxes at same time.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String FilePath = "F:/ISTP Testing/Module 2/Seleniume/project/Spaco_DataEntryTest_ContactPage.xls";
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        // TO get the access to the sheet
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        String BaseURL="http://istp.in/changathionlinebeta/contact_us.php";
        WebDriver wd=new FirefoxDriver();
        wd.get(BaseURL); 


        // To get the number of rows present in sheet
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
        // To get the number of columns present in sheet
        int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
        for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                System.out.print(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                if(col%2==0)
                {
                    wd.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                }else{
                    wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }

        wd.close();
        System.exit(0); 
    }
}
```

[image: My Text Boxes]

Comment: if it's working why you can't do it to the rest of the fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this -

```
 for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

    for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
        System.out.print(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t"); //don't understand what you want to achieve using this
        Thread.sleep(3000);
         switch(col){
             Case 0: wd.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                     break;
              Case 1: wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                     break;
              Case 2: wd.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                     break;
              Case 3: wd.findElement(By.id("mob")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                     break;
              Case 4: wd.findElement(By.id("address")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
                     break;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Though the solution might have worked for you but ideally you should create a separate class for this page like @Leon has suggested below. It will make your code,data more reusable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Rudziankoŭ right but.

1 > Create `class SubmitPageObject` with all the properties (name, email, address ...)

2 > in your program create method that get the information from the workbook and assign it to `List<SubmitPageObject> spo = new List<SubmitPageObject>();`

```
..
spo.Add(new SubmitPageObject(name,email,...))
```

3 > and the final step is to loop over the list and :

```
wd.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(spo[i].name);
wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(spo[i].email);
wd.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys(spo[i].phone);
```

...

Comment: +1. This is the best way to parameterize which is often used. But the questioner is not using POM as it appears from his code. So i reconstructed his logic around switch statements.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about [single responsibility principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)? Your code will be much more maintainable, readable, extendable if you divide responsibilities into different methods.

```
 class Test{
      List<String> getNamesFromSheet(){ ...
      List<String> getEmailsFromSheet(){ ...
      List<String> getPhonesFromSheet(){ ...
      List<String> getMobFromSheet(){ ...
      List<String> getAdressFromSheet(){ ...
      void fillInTable(){
           for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                 wd.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(getNamesFromSheet().get(i));
                 wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(getEmailsFromSheet().get(i));
                 //...

           }
      }
```

Comment: best create new type SubmitPageObject and insert all to List<SubmitPageObject>